# React-redux createStore is deprecated in typescript but not javascript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

So this piece of code works without problems in my react js app.

```
import reducers from "./reducer";
import middlewareFunctions from "./middleware";
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";

const middleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  const fn = Object.keys(middlewareFunctions).find(
    (key) => key === action.type
  );
  if (fn) return middlewareFunctions[fn](store, next, action);
  return next(action);
};
export default createStore(
  combineReducers(reducers),
  {},
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
);
```

However when I convert to react typescript it shows me that `createStore` is deprecated.
And its recommended to use the `configureStore` method of the `@reduxjs/toolkit` package, which replaces `createStore`.

I read the details on Redux docs page: https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today
But I am still struggling to understand how to adapt my code for `configureStore`

**1. Question**: Why is createStore deprecated on my React Typescript app but not on React Javascript?

**2. Question**: What is the correct approach now? Simply switching createStore to configureStore does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### `createStore` is also deprecated in javascript: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/pull/4336/

> 1. Question: Why is createStore deprecated on my React Typescript app but not on React Javascript?

- It's also deprecated in javascript https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/pull/4336/
- It's easier to use `configureStore` with typescript (from all of my experience with redux) because with `configureStore` you can easily create your state types, dispatch types etc...

Now the recommanded way to use do a redux application is with `configureStore`.

FYI:
[`configureStore` use `createStore` internally](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/64a30d83384d77bcbc59231fa32aa2f1acd67020/packages/toolkit/src/configureStore.ts#L195)

> 2. Question: What is the correct approach now? Simply switching createStore to configureStore does not work.

The correct approach now is to use `configureStore` from redux-toolkit.